# 2LIS_17_I3HDR data is not being pushed into ODQDATA

Tags: sap-bw, sap-data-services

We are extracting SAP PM data to BO Data Services (BODS) using Operational Data Provisioning (ODP), and have successfully done this for notifications. We've gone through all the LBWE config for `2LIS_17_I3HDR` & `2LIS_17_I3OPER` and it is set as Direct Delta.

We have successfully populated and extracted from the Setup tables, and have initialised the delta queue with the function `sap_extractor_delta_initialize( )`. We can see these in `ODQMON`. However, for work orders *no data is being pushed into the `ODQDATA`* table.

When debugging the extractor I can see it find the subscription but it then closes with NO_DATA. In the `ODQDATA` table I can see other Datasources but not the two `2LIS_17_I3xxx`.
Our BW extractors were all installed from BI_CONT already enabled for ODP.
We are running:

- SAP_BASIS    740 0025
- BI_CONT      757 0027

Is there something else I should've done?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is in SAP notes 509140, 1850433, & 2739105.